# Showing and hiding table row when item is selted

Tags: javascript, html, css

Having trouble getting this HTML/java script to work correctly, been working at is for a day now. Looked on line and found what I have coded here. I want it when the page loads to not display the "Colors*" row. When I select the size of shirt from the drop down then it will show the color options.

As of right now that kinda works, the table that has the colors and radio buttons in it resizes and doesn't display correctly, matching the above row in length, so this is were I'm stuck. Along with the radio buttons allowing to select all of them instead of just one.

I added two images showing what it looks like. 
Edit: Buttons problem has been fixed

Im looking to do this with just javascript, no jquery.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jsForm.js"></script> 
<title>Javascript with Forms</title>
<style type="text/css">
table{
        width: 800px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="#">
    <table border="1">
    <caption>T-Shirt Selection</caption>
    <tr><td style="100px;"></td><td style="150px;"></td><td     style="50px;"></td><td  style="50px;"></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Selection</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                T_Shirt 1:  
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="shirts" onchange="showButton(this)">
                    <option value="0" selected >Choose T-Shirt </option>
                    <option value="1" >Small $10.99</option>
                    <option value="2" >Medium $12.99</option>
                    <option value="3" >Large $14.99</option>
                    <option value="4" >X-Large $15.99</option>
                    <option value="5" >XX-Large $15.99</option>
                </select> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="qty" maxlength="4" size="4" /> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="qty" maxlength="10" size="10" /> 
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr id="hidden_button" style="display:none;">
            <td colspan="1">Color.*</td>
            <td colspan="3">
            <input type="radio" name="Back" value="Black" /> Black
            <input type="radio"name="White" value="White" />White
            <input type="radio"name="Blue" value="Blue" />Blue
            <input type="radio" name="Red" value="Red"/>Red
            </td>   
        </tr>        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
function showButton(elem){
if(elem.value == 0){
    document.getElementById('hidden_button').style.display = "none";
}else if(elem.value > 0){
    document.getElementById('hidden_button').style.display = "block";
}
```

}

here is what im talking about 
[image]
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Lol - size of what?

Comment: the size of the t-shirt? what it says in the above question? or are you talking about what the table resizes too?

Comment: You need to proofread your question, unless you're refering to the Bristol chart for sizes.

Comment: Size of .....??

Comment: I was giving away free editing points obsessively.... :/ It was hard to keep on all the people commenting and editing it. fixed it thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `display = "table-row"` in your script, not `display = "block"`

And it's recommended to toggle a class instead of change an elements style, as in sample 2.

```js
function showButton(elem) {
  if (elem.value == 0) {
    document.getElementById('hidden_button').style.display = "none";
  } else if (elem.value > 0) {
    document.getElementById('hidden_button').style.display = "table-row";
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 800px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <table border="1">
    <caption>T-Shirt Selection</caption>
    <tr>
      <td style="100px;"></td>
      <td style="150px;"></td>
      <td style="50px;"></td>
      <td style="50px;"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Selection</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        T_Shirt 1:
      </td>
      <td>
        <select id="shirts" onchange="showButton(this)">
          <option value="0" selected>Choose T-Shirt</option>
          <option value="1">Small $10.99</option>
          <option value="2">Medium $12.99</option>
          <option value="3">Large $14.99</option>
          <option value="4">X-Large $15.99</option>
          <option value="5">XX-Large $15.99</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="qty" maxlength="4" size="4" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="qty" maxlength="10" size="10" />
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr id="hidden_button" style="display:none;">
      <td colspan="1">Color.*</td>
      <td colspan="3">
        <input type="radio" name="Back" value="Black" />Black
        <input type="radio" name="White" value="White" />White
        <input type="radio" name="Blue" value="Blue" />Blue
        <input type="radio" name="Red" value="Red" />Red
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Sample 2

```js
function showButton(elem) {
  if (elem.value == 0) {
    document.getElementById('hidden_button').classList.remove('show');
  } else if (elem.value > 0) {
    document.getElementById('hidden_button').classList.add('show');
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 800px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#hidden_button {
  display: none;
}
#hidden_button.show {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <table border="1">
    <caption>T-Shirt Selection</caption>
    <tr>
      <td style="100px;"></td>
      <td style="150px;"></td>
      <td style="50px;"></td>
      <td style="50px;"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Selection</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        T_Shirt 1:
      </td>
      <td>
        <select id="shirts" onchange="showButton(this)">
          <option value="0" selected>Choose T-Shirt</option>
          <option value="1">Small $10.99</option>
          <option value="2">Medium $12.99</option>
          <option value="3">Large $14.99</option>
          <option value="4">X-Large $15.99</option>
          <option value="5">XX-Large $15.99</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="qty" maxlength="4" size="4" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="qty" maxlength="10" size="10" />
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr id="hidden_button">
      <td colspan="1">Color.*</td>
      <td colspan="3">
        <input type="radio" name="Back" value="Black" />Black
        <input type="radio" name="White" value="White" />White
        <input type="radio" name="Blue" value="Blue" />Blue
        <input type="radio" name="Red" value="Red" />Red
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Ill have to look into the display elements a little more next time.

Comment: @whisk Yepp, will help :) ... and made a 2:nd sample as a suggestion

Answer (score 1):

error you are having in the following section

```
<input type="radio" name="Back" value="Black" /> Black
<input type="radio"name="White" value="White" />White
<input type="radio"name="Blue" value="Blue" />Blue
<input type="radio" name="Red" value="Red"/>Red
```

as you have put different name for the radio button, all of them became independent. to make them all in a group put same name to all of them.

```
<input type="radio" name="color" value="Black" /> Black
<input type="radio"name="color" value="White" />White
<input type="radio"name="color" value="Blue" />Blue
<input type="radio" name="color" value="Red"/>Red
```

Comment: That fixed the radio button problem, thank you! Its a simple error on my part.

Answer (score 1):

First you must repair the first tr. There you have 5 td but your colspan is running about 3 cols and all other tr (less the last hidden) have 4 cols!!!

It is bad code if you write (like in your first tr)

```
style="100px;"
```

You forgot a style-attribute like width/height/etc

It is not necessary to write

```
colspan="1"
```

This is the default setting for td.

Comment: I had the first row for testing to space things out. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use on click Add class script here      `$('#shirts').on('click', function() { $(this).addClass('current').hidden_button(); });`